# Display a 8 digit hex offset 0x?

Tags: c

I am only working on the first one so far to display the hex offset "0" I am trying to find a way for the program to open the file and display an 8-digit hex offset with a leading 0x indicator. I am trying to have it run something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 offset      0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  a  b   c  d  e  f  ascii
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x00000000
0x00000010 
0x00000020
```

and so on...

any tips/suggestions would be great. Also I am also seeking for a "cleaner" way to display the banner, instead of having to **printf** the individual lines and so forth.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I have the program display the hex offset with the leading 0x. I tried to insert my code for that part but I can't quite pinpoint how, so any tips would be appreciated.
2. Is there any cleaner way to display the header?

Thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct winsize terminal;
    FILE* fp;
    int a, c, column, row, lines;

    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &terminal, argv[2]);

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");                          //set open for argv[1] and set it to read mode
    column = terminal.ws_col;
    row = terminal.ws_row;
    lines = atoi(argv[2]);

    // printf("Rows are: %d\n", row);
    // printf("Columns are: %d\n", column);

    if (argc < 3)                                      //Argument checking, at least three to run
    {
        printf("You need atleast 3 arguments to run!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening '%s'.\n", argv[1]);             //if not file is specified then close program and give an error
        exit(1);
    }
    c = fgetc(fp);                                //set c to fgetc

    if (column < 80 || row < 20)                               //if temrinal window is less than 80x20, display an error and exit
    {
        printf("Terminal window must be at least 80x20!\n");              //display error and close program if column criteria isn't met
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
    while(!feof(fp))                                   //if file is entered, display a test message (this is where later on I will show hex value)

    {
        printf("Good Job! You picked a file to manipulate!!\n");
        exit(1);
     }
     */
    if (lines == 0)                                       //if 0 is entered for argv[2], display all the lines, 512 byte file
    {
        printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"); //**this is where I try to display character/hex banner**
        printf("offset      0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  a  b   c  d  e  f  ascii\n");
        printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        for (c == 0x200) ; //**This is where I try to get the 8 digit 0x hex offset**
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "%04x", c);
        }
    }
    else if (lines == 20)
    {
        printf("This will print out 20 lines\n");
    }
    else if (lines == 30)
    {
        printf("This will print out 30 lines\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please Enter a Valid Number!\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);                                        //close fp

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: RTF(ine)M! Read the `printf` manpage.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
printf("0x%08x\n", 0xDEADBEEF);
```

Comment: Thank you, would I have to use a 'for' loop to keep repeating the different sets of hex values to fill up my offset column?